# Implement new JavaFX components using GroovyFX?

Tags: java, groovy, javafx, javafx-2, groovyfx

We are using [GroovyFX](http://groovyfx-project.github.com/) in our project, to build our user interfaces.

It already provides support for all the native UI components, such as `TextArea` and `HTMLEditor`, but we are also building a custom UI component (that actually extends `javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor`).

What would be the best way to implement support for this new component in GroovyFX? By *support* I mean being able to call it like any other component:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    def myArea

    GroovyFX.start {
        new SceneGraphBuilder().stage(width: 1024, height: 700, visible: true) {
            scene {
                vbox {
                    myArea = htmlEditor()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GroovyFX-users list:

> You would need to create a new factory in order to get the
>   SceneGraphBuilder to recognize your myCustomEditor node.
>
> But the simple solution to your problem is to write:
>
> scene {   vbox {
>       myArea = node(new MyCustomEditor())   } }
>
> Using node() you can add an instance of any object that is-a node to
>   the scene graph.

Answer (score 3):

you may want to have a look at

https://github.com/groovyfx-project/groovyfx/blob/develop/groovyfx/src/demo/groovy/CustomFieldDemo.groovy

which adds a new node type to the SceneGraphBuilder in essentially one line.

happy grooving'
@mittie